# How to extrude inwards through face?

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

I've been trying to figure out how to extrude a face inwards and when hitting another face going through it and removing the face. I basically would want an uninterrupted extrusion. This can be achieved by removing the unwanted face and then filling in the parts of the face that aren't interrupting the extrusion. But this is a tedious and not very good method. I was wondering if there was any better way to do this?

*Block before extrusion*
[image: Nonmodified block]

*Block after extrusion*
[image: Block where inset has been extruded inwards]

*Face that I would like to be removed*
[image: Face I want to be removed]

*I would like to keep the faces that aren't interrupting the extrusion*
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you start modelling from the lowest part of your object, so you don't need to extrude part of the plane inward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've got you right, after <kbd>I</kbd> insetting top and bottom faces simultaneously, it could be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Extrude Manifold, followed by <kbd>X</kbd> > Delete Faces.

[image]

Comment: oh ok you must be right about the question

Comment: @moonboots Dunno.... I would never want to make geometry like this, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can select the bottom face and all the side faces, go into the *Face* panel and choose *Intersect (Boolean)*:

[image]

In the *Operator* box choose *Difference* and *Fast*:

[image]